# get a vaule of an object and add another value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<object>` I want to get the "data" of that `<object>` and I want to add the value `"target= _blank"`. 
All this when I click.

"when I click on something, get the "data" and add the "value" "target= _blank".

Comment: So you have an object tag on the page? Maybe add an example of the HTML and what you tried.

Comment: Here's a possible start: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `getElementsByTagName`, `addEventListener` and `setAttribute` :

```
window.onload = function(){
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
      alert(this.getAttribute("data"));
      this.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    });
  }
}
```